# How can I execute PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following question. I've created a stored procedure in PostgreSQL and I have can not execute it, I've tried to use **exec** , but I get wierd error.

Here is my stored function:

```
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS checkName();
CREATE PROCEDURE checkName(c_Name varchar)
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare notify_msg text := 0;
  BEGIN
    if(LENGTH(c_Name) > 41) THEN
         notify_msg = 'Restaurant name can not be longer than 41 characters.';
        END IF;
  END;
$$;

COMMENT ON PROCEDURE checkName IS 'This procedure checks if the restaurant name is longer than 40 characters';
```

And this is how I tried to execute it:

```
exec checkName('ThisIsTest');
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
 ERROR: FEHLER:  Funktion »checkname« existiert bereits mit den selben Argumenttypen
```

Is there a different way to execute stored procedure in PostgreSQL.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name May I  ask you one more thing ?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you have to use

$ Call functioname

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html